# How do I print a specific message if the user inputs the same string twice in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am practicing my Python skills. I am currently on week 4 and stuck on doing a specific task. If a user enter the same string twice in my self.songs input I want to print a message saying "You can't enter the same song twice. Try again".

How can I do this? Also, is there a way for the user the use commas instead of white space to separate each string while inputing their favourite songs?

```
  class User:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ''
        self.songs = ()
        self.movies = ()
        self.sports = ()

    def tops(self):
        self.name = input("What's you're full name?:")
        while True:
            self.songs = input('Hi ' + self.name + ', what is your top 5 favorite songs?:').split()
            if len(self.songs) > 5:
                print('You entered more than 5 songs. Try again')
            elif len(self.songs) < 5:
                print('You entered less than 5 songs. Try again')
            elif len(self.songs) == 5:
                for song in self.songs:
                    print(song)
                confirm_input = input('Do you confirm?')
                if confirm_input == 'Yes':
                    print(type(self.songs))
                    print(self.songs)
                    break
                elif confirm_input == 'No':
                    continue


quizUser = User()
quizUser.tops()
```

Comment: `confirm_input = input('Type Yes to confirm')`, So, the user knows to type `Yes` instead of the usual `y` :)

Comment: Not to criticize the question or answers.  However sometimes taking a different approach can be useful.  If you refactored to ask titles in a loop until 5, you’d easily achieve non-duplication by checking in the list. Plus, you could enter *You Can't Always Get What You Want*, which is currently impossible here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set) to get no same elements, and compare it's length with the normal list by using `!=`.

add this to your code:

```
elif len(set(self.songs)) != len(self.songs):
    print('You can\'t enter the same song twice. Try again')
```

*by the way, `\'` means escaping `'`.*

The whole code:

```
class User:
        def __init__(self):
            self.name = ''
            self.songs = ()
            self.movies = ()
            self.sports = ()
    
        def tops(self):
            self.name = input("What's you're full name?:")
            while True:
                self.songs = input('Hi ' + self.name + ', what is your top 5 favorite songs?:').split()
                if len(self.songs) > 5:
                    print('You entered more than 5 songs. Try again')
                elif len(self.songs) < 5:
                    print('You entered less than 5 songs. Try again')
                elif len(self.songs) != len(set(self.songs)):
                    print('You can\'t enter the same song twice. Try again')
                elif len(self.songs) == 5:
                    for song in self.songs:
                        print(song)
                    confirm_input = input('Do you confirm?')
                    if confirm_input == 'Yes':
                        print(type(self.songs))
                        print(self.songs)
                        break
                    elif confirm_input == 'No':
                        continue
    
    
quizUser = User()
quizUser.tops()
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use a `set` to get unique element, then compare its length with the answer length

```
if len(set(self.songs)) != len(self.songs):
    print("You can't enter the same song twice. Try again")    
elif len(self.songs) > 5:
    print('You entered more than 5 songs. Try again')
elif len(self.songs) < 5:
    print('You entered less than 5 songs. Try again')
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count the occurrence of each element and set the `flag` to 1 if a duplicate exists.
Following is the modified code:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ''
        self.songs = ()
        self.movies = ()
        self.sports = ()

    def tops(self):
        self.name = input("What's you're full name?:")
        while True:
            ########################################
            #Flag variable to check if the repetition occured
            flag = 0
            self.songs = input('Hi ' + self.name + ', what is your top 5 favorite songs?:').split()
            #Loop over the songs
            for i in self.songs:
                #Check the count of each song, if greater than 1 set flag variable to 1 and empty songs.
                if self.songs.count(i)>1:
                    print("You can't enter the same song twice. Try again")
                    self.songs = ()
                    flag = 1
            #Check if flag is 1, if true exit the current iteration
            if flag == 1:
                continue
            #######################################
            if len(self.songs) > 5:
                print('You entered more than 5 songs. Try again')
            elif len(self.songs) < 5:
                print('You entered less than 5 songs. Try again')
            elif len(self.songs) == 5:
                for song in self.songs:
                    print(song)
                confirm_input = input('Do you confirm?')
                if confirm_input == 'Yes':
                    print(type(self.songs))
                    print(self.songs)
                    break
                elif confirm_input == 'No':
                    continue


quizUser = User()
quizUser.tops()
```

Comment: You have so more to learn, there is other much faster and easier way to check for duplicate, use of a collections.Counter, or a 'set' like the other answers ;)

Comment: Also in your code `flag = 1` could be directly replaced with 'continue'

Comment: @azro If continue is used, it will exit only the for loop and the lines below the for loop will execute. No libraries were used considering they were not supposed to be used. The aim was to develop the logic.